# Why does ProGuard keep the onCreate() method?

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but I simply don't understand why this is happening: As per the default proguard.cfg file, I define the following rule:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

as far as I understand, this means: keep any `Activity` class as an entry point, but feel free to shrink/obfuscate/optimize anything inside it (otherwise I'd have to use e.g. the `<methods>` wildcard to preserve methods, too, right?).

Now my test Activity looks like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }

    public void unusedMethod() {
    }
}
```

If I now export a signed APK, and ProGuard is invoked, it will remove `unusedMethod` as expected, but it will keep the `onCreate` method and not obfuscate its name. Why is that?

Comment: Moreover, if I add a POJO `A` that contains a single method `M` invoked from MyActivity, and don't specify any keep rules for it, then ProGuard will keep `A` and obfuscate its name, but it will *not* obfuscate `M`... I'm confused.

Comment: Ah -- actually, I think that's because ProGuard decided to inline that method, since it was a one-liner... Makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding of the configuuration options is correct. However, ProGuard can't remove or rename your `onCreate` method, because it overrides the onCreate method in android.app.Activity. Renaming it would break the application. Methods that don't override library methods, like `unusedMethod`, can safely be removed, inlined, or at least renamed.

The method `M` should be renamed, unless you are specifying some -keep option for it. You can check that with the option `-whyareyoukeeping`.

Comment: also, see my other comment why ProGuard was not obfuscating M -- I looked at the byte code, and it actually inlined the call, so there was no method M anymore...