# Why Proguard renames Activity's onCreate() method

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a Jar from a library project which has some Activitys, Services. It's OK when I dont user proguard, but when I run proguardJar， Activity's onCreate() method will be renamed as a,b,c... But Service's onCreate() is ok.

Normally, proGuard should keep the onCreate().
[Why does ProGuard keep the onCreate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926700/why-does-proguard-keep-the-oncreate-method)

Here is the gradle file.

```
import com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
}

task buildJar(dependsOn: ['build'], type: Jar) {

    appendix = "demo"
    baseName = "androidJar"
    version = "1.0.0"
    classifier = "release"

    extension = "jar"
    archiveName = "AndroidJarDemo.jar"

    def srcClassDir = [project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/intermediates/classes/release"];
    from srcClassDir

    exclude "**/BuildConfig.class"
    exclude "**/BuildConfig\$*.class"
    exclude "**/R.class"
    exclude "**/R\$*.class"
}

task proguardJar(dependsOn: ['buildJar'], type: ProGuardTask) {
    configuration android.getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    configuration 'proguard-rules.pro'

    String inJar = buildJar.archivePath.getAbsolutePath()

    injars inJar
    outjars inJar.substring(0, inJar.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/proguard-${buildJar.archiveName}"

    dontshrink

    Plugin plugin = getPlugins().hasPlugin(AppPlugin) ?
            getPlugins().findPlugin(AppPlugin) :
            getPlugins().findPlugin(LibraryPlugin)
    if (plugin != null) {
        List<String> runtimeJarList
        if (plugin.getMetaClass().getMetaMethod("getRuntimeJarList")) {
            runtimeJarList = plugin.getRuntimeJarList()
        } else if (android.getMetaClass().getMetaMethod("getBootClasspath")) {
            runtimeJarList = android.getBootClasspath()
        } else {
            runtimeJarList = plugin.getBootClasspath()
        }

        for (String runtimeJar : runtimeJarList) {
            libraryjars(runtimeJar)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is part of activity

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ......
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                MyService.getInstance().addListener(mBaseCallback);
            }
        ......
        }
```

The onCreate method will be renamed like this.

```
protected void a(@Nullable Bundle var1) {
        super.onCreate(var1);
        e.a().a(this.c);
    }
```

Here is the proguard-rules.pro.

```
#sdk
-dontwarn **


-keep class com.lib.activity.**
-keep class com.lib.fragment.**

#keep native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.design.**

-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder
```

Comment: Could you show us [part of] the Activity's code?

Comment: This is belong `proguard-rules.pro` config file. You need setup to skip some Class. It will pass and don't rename them

Comment: @mdtuyen keep all the activity? I just want to hide some code.

Comment: pls show your `proguard-rules.pro` file

Comment: @Nikola I have shown part of the code, it just like a normal activity

Comment: @mdtuyen proguard-rules.pro is shown

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want rename any item you need add that item to list keep on proguard-rules.pro file:

Here is a recommend for proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontnote
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

#keep all classes that might be used in XML layouts
-keep public class * extends android.os.Bundle
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.Fragment

#keep all public and protected methods that could be used by java reflection
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    public protected <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-renamesourcefileattribute ProGuard
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-printmapping outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Keep the public protected <methods> is OK, but I only want to expose the onCreate method.

Comment: I had built another application project (not library project), the onCreated method will not be renamed.

Comment: I dont test but you can try: `-keepclassmembernames class *  extends android.app.Activity {
    public protected <methods>;
}`

Comment: or try add more: `-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }`

Comment: I know keep the public protected <methods> is OK, but normally, the onCreate will not be renamed. [ProGuard keep the onCreate() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926700/why-does-proguard-keep-the-oncreate-method)

Answer (score 0):

Proguard runs 3 stages - it strips unused or what it thinks is unused code, optimizes and obfuscates the code (not necessarily in this order).

What you're seeing is the obfuscation step. A way to prevent this is to add `-dontobfuscate` to your proguard configuration.

Obfuscation is turned on by default, applying `-dontobfuscate` will disable the entire step. I'm not entirely sure you want this, so please weight the approaches. There might also be another way to keep the class names intact that I'm not aware.

Comment: But I also want to obfuscate the code. Normally, the onCreate will not be renamed. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926700/why-does-proguard-keep-the-oncreate-method)